# How to modularize class methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I an new in OOP in PHP.

I am looking for a best practice how the modularize a php class. What I want is to define my class and then "load" methods for this class by including php files.

Here is some code to illustrate what I mean:

```
<?php /* module.php */

class MyClass_Module {

    public function foo(){
        print_r("Hello welt");
    }

}

<?php /* somewhere else */

class MyClass {

    function __construct($optionen = array()){
        require_once("module.php");
    }


}

$myObj = new MyClass();
$myObj->foo();
```

Comment: If you need to call functions of `module.php` then you can use inheritance of class

Comment: I think you're looking for inheritance.

Comment: It’s hard for me to explain, but I want to extend MyClass itself and not use `class Bar extends MyClass`

Comment: I found a solution by using traits – see answer in the Answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using traits:

```
<?php /* module.php */

trait MyClass_Module {

    public function foo(){
        print_r("Hallo Welt");
    }

}


<?php /* somewhere else */

require_once("module.php");

class MyClass {

    use MyClass_Module;

}

$myObj = new MyClass();

$myObj->foo();
```

Thanks to all who gave me answers – I have learned a lot by looking at your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php).

Try this:

```
Class MyClass() {
    public function Foo() {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}

Class MyExtendedClass extends MyClass() {
    public function Bar() {
        return 'World';
    }
    public function FooBar() {
        return Parent::Foo().' '.$this->Bar();
    }
}

$myObj = new MyExtendedClass;
echo $myObj->Foo(); // Outputs 'Hello';
echo $myObj->Bar(); // Outputs 'World';
echo $myObj->FooBar(); // Outputs 'Hello World';
```

To keep them in separate files you should look at using an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

**UPDATE**

If you're not trying to access a related function, but trying to deal with several other classes then what you need is [Dependency Injection](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-in-php--net-28146). You instantiate the classes as normal then pass them in to other classes to use them. Try this:

```
/* myworkerclass.php */
Class MyWorkerClass() {
    public function Foo()
    {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}

/* mypageclass.php */
Class MyPageClass() {
    private $dbConn;
    private $myWorkerObj;

    public function __construct(mysqli $dbConn, MyWorkerClass $myWorkerObj)
    {
        $this->dbConn = $dbConn;
        $this->myWorkerObj = $myWorkerObj;
    }

    public function Bar() {
        return ' World';
    }

    public function OutputFooBar()
    {
        return $this->myWorkerObj->Foo().$this->Bar();
    }
}

/* index.php */
$dbConn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
$myWorkerObj = new MyWorkerClass;
$myPageObj = new MyPageClass($dbConn, $myWorkerObj);

echo $myPageObj->OutputFooBar(); // Outputs 'Hello World'
echo $myPageObj->myWorkerObj->Foo(); // Outputs 'Hello'
echo $myPageObj->Bar(); // Outputs ' World'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this, but if doing so, I only can only add methods of one class – but I want to load methods of several classes.

Comment: Your welcome, don't forget to mark the answer as correct by clicking on the tick next to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but my question is not answered (see edited comment above).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to know is the [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) functionality.

`__autoload($class)` lets you instantiate any class provided that the `require` or `include` is inside in the __autoload() function.. this is a very powerful feature for php oop since it lets you include one php file that has the __autoload function and all the classes that is stated in the function will automatically be included and instanciated.. for more information, you can visit the link I provided..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at the **Decorator** design pattern.

See: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator/php